# Issue: Installing R on openSUSE Leap 15.0: "liblzma library and headers are required"

Tags: r, opensuse, r-server

I have tried installing R v3.5.0 (from https://cloud.r-project.org). I downloaded the .tar.gz file, unzipped it and ran

```
./configure
```

It is giving me the error below:

> configure: error: "liblzma library and headers are required"

I opened yast2 and checked whether it is installed properly or not. The terminal shows me liblzma5 version 5.2.3 is installed.
Why is it not able to find the correct files. Do I have to change some filepaths? If yes whichones?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This indicates that the header files needed for development are not installed. You can install them using

```
zypper install lzma-devel
```

as `root` or with `sudo`.

Comment: On opensuse/tumbleweed `zypper install lzma-devel` is automatically translated to `zypper install xz-devel`.

Answer (score 1):

for ubuntu people:

```
apt install liblzma-dev
```